# Error while installing a signed eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation

After signing an eclipse plugin as described here

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-plugin-sigs/index.html

I get this error while installing the plugin.

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=SGXXProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,myPlugin.feature,1.0.1.201210210823.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 3161fbf11454ed135d19980926143bc3 and found 0c213a15f4ae34c1b2e65ab43932e308.

What should cause this error ?

Answer (score 0):

A few update sites can be a bit unreliable sometimes, try installing the required plug-in a few hours later. If the issue is still a problem, try contacting the developera at their mailing list with the issue.

In this case, I believe there is a problem (missing definition) in the update site, ping the devs, maybe it is a known issue. Or the downloaded file might damaged, did you used a Wi-fi connection for the installation?

Comment: I made the signing myself, and the plugin is local in my hard disk.
and it woks fine without signing